# Using print.css with @media print elsewhere

Tags: css, media-queries

I've got a webpage that uses a site global print.css stylesheet to render the page for print.  The page also uses sitewide classes for divs, headers, etc.

I need to increase the width of the body and the size of the font of this page in the print version.  I don't have access to edit the global print.css, and would prefer not to make my changes there because the changes will affect other pages that I don't want to change (due to the use of global styles, div classes, etc.).

Fortunately, this page does have its own stylesheet, foo.css that I can edit to make changes that will only affect this page.

Further complicating this is that the page has an inline style on the body class that I need to change for print only.

Normally I would edit foo.css with my style change, using !important to override the inline style as needed, but what I can't figure out is:

- Can I use @media print { body {width: 900px; !important;}} in foo.css and have it work even though I already have a print.css?

I've been trying to test this in Firebug (with Web Developer Toolbar), but if I add the @media print call to foo.css, nothing seems to happen.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible.  Things to check:

1. is foo.css included with `all` media?
2. You shouldn't have a `;` before `!important`.
3. Does your `@media` selector have higher [specificity](http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php) than the inline style?

Comment: 1) I set media="all" on foo.css but this seems to make no difference; 2) The extra ; was a typo in my question - doesn't exist in the actual stylesheet; 3) specificity trips me up a lot - it would seem the inline style has a higher specificity because it is inline (1,0,0,0),  whereas div.body would have a specificity of (0,0,1,1) (according to the calculator). I thought !important would trump that. I guess that's not the case. But then how does !important ever work if inline styles always have the highest specificity? I think I am confusing myself here..

Comment: @Eclipse no idea on why the third question exists because the inline style will always have a highest specificity than any CSS styles and you cannot change that fact. I'd recommend (this is an ugly fix) to create 2 divs/span: The current one and a hidden one, maybe with a class like 'showOnPrint', that way you can add that class to the media print